# Calling java code from C++: exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I am trying to call some java code from a JNI C++ function and I get an exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

The C++ code where the java code is called is a callback function called from another native library.
This code was working perfectly fine when I used the setup described in 
[here](http://morgwai.pl/ndkTutorial/):

Basically an APK that was using a JNI and that JNI was making calls to a native libray compiled elsewhere).

But then I wanted to compile all my code in the AOSP, so I put the code of my native library, the JNI and the APK code in vendor/MyCode/MyApp. It compiles fine, native methods called from the java work OK but java code being called from the JNI now crashes all.

Here is the java code of the method I want to call from the JNI:

```
package com.android.mycode.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    private native int powerOn();

    ...

public void ndefRead(int tech, int protocol, byte[] ndef)
{
    Log.d(tag, "ndefRead()");
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
    msg.what = MSG_NDEF_READ_RECEIVED;
    msg.obj = ndef;
    msg.arg1 = tech;
    msg.arg2 = protocol;
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
}

...
}
```

My JNI code where I register the java data:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_android_mycode_myapp_MainActivity_powerOn(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)
{
    LOGD("calling powerOn()"); //Or ANDROID_LOG_INFO, ...

    env->GetJavaVM(&javaVM);
    jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
    activityClass = (jclass) env->NewGlobalRef(cls);
    activityObj = env->NewGlobalRef(obj);
    ...
    return status;
}
```

The JNI code of the callback function where the java code is called:

```
void EventCallback(UINT8 event, tEVT_CBACK_DATA* eventData)
{
LOGD("EventCallback() - event: 0x%x", event);

switch (event)
{
    case NDEF_READ_EVT:
    {
        LOGD("EventCallback() - NDEF_READ_EVT - data length: 0x%x", eventData->ndefReadEvt.length);

        JNIEnv *env;
        javaVM->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);

        jmethodID ndefReadID = env->GetMethodID(activityClass, "ndefRead", "(II[B)V");
        if (ndefReadID == 0)
        {
            LOGD("Function ndefRead() not found");
            return;
        }

        jbyteArray result = env->NewByteArray(eventData->ndefReadEvt.length);
        if (result != NULL)
        {
            env->SetByteArrayRegion(result, 0, eventData->ndefReadEvt.length, (jbyte *) eventData->ndefReadEvt.p_ndef);
        }

        env->CallVoidMethod(activityObj, ndefReadID, eventData->ndefReadEvt.tech, eventData->ndefReadEvt.protocol, result);
        javaVM->DetachCurrentThread();
    }
        break;
}
```

The makefile of the JNI looks like this:

```
LOCAL_MODULE    := libinterface
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := interface.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libnfc-nci
```

And when executing this code I get the following exception/error message:

```
Pending exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError thrown by 'unknown throw location'
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lcom/android/mycode/myapp/MainActivity;.ndefRead(II[B)V"
```

I have looked at several other problems of this type reported on this site but could not quite found something that is similar to mine. If someone has an idea it would be greatly appreciated.

Edited to add code of ndefRead() function and makefile of JNI.

Comment: As you are attaching to the thread is `activityClass` valid to be used on this thread? Had a quick look at the JNI docs and it's not clear to me.

Comment: I think using the activityClass = (jclass) env->NewGlobalRef(cls) code should do the trick. And as I said this code was working fine before I put and compiled everything on the AOPS (vendor folder).

Comment: Yes, using the class reference should be fine since a global reference to it was created. One potential issue I see - depending on where the call to `EventCallback` originates from - is that `AttachCurrentThread` essentially is a NOP if the thread already is attached to the VM, so calling `DetachCurrentThread` on a thread that already was attached prior to `AttachCurrentThread` can cause problems.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause another exception than NoSuchMethod? Because I already had issues with the AttachCurrentThread (i was not calling the detach code when exiting the app) and the error message was different.

Comment: `package com.android.mycode.myapp;` vs `Java_com_android_st_nfcnintendothread_MainActivity_powerOn`

Comment: Yeah, that would lead to _"detaching thread with interp frames"_ or something like that. I was just bringing it up as a potential issue in your code.

Comment: What does the definition of nRead() look like?

Comment: Added code of ndefRead() in question text

Answer (score 0):

These errors are usually caused by the make file or wrong file naming.

I didn't see any `static { System.loadLibrary("your-c-module"); }`, as defined in android MK, e.g:

```
#android.mk

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := your-c-module
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += fancy-library
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl
```

Also, I don't know if you filtered it out or not, but if `Java_com_android_st_nfcnintendothread_MainActivity_powerOn` is your c function, then your package name should be: `com.android.st.nfcnintendothread` and it's function: `MainActivity.powerOn`.

I am just spit-balling here, hopefully you'll find something useful in the above.

Comment: Yes I tried and filtered the naming a bit, forgot some it seems. My JNI function name has the same name as the java package. Here is what my JNI makefile looks like: _italic_ **bold** `
LOCAL_MODULE    := libinterface
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := interface.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libnfc-nci"

Comment: I re-edited the code to reflect current implementation